# Display 12hh format in Android TimePicker Dialog Fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm doing an android app where I have to choose a specific time.

This what I've done so far:

```
 public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // use the current time as the default values for the picker
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


    // create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, false
            ); // DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity())
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
{   
    view.setIs24HourView(false);
    String time;

    if ( minute < 10  ) {
        _minute =  ":0" + minute;
    } else {
        _minute = ":" + minute;
    }


    Log.w("TimePicker", "Time = " + time);


    EditText activityButton = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etTime);
    activityButton.setText( time );


}
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
 6:30 PM
```

But all I get is:

```
18:30
```

I want to 12 H format not the 24h. How can I do this? Help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/07/time-picker-in-android-example.html#.Utd3-t_FsUQ. check this if it helps

Comment: @Raghunandan the problem with solution in that url is 12:00PM becomes 12:00AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
 int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

to

```
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

bcoz I see on

```
public static final int HOUR_OF_DAY
```

Added in API level 1

Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `TimePickerDialog` class to achieve this using its constructor:

```
 TimePickerDialog (Context context, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)
```

Check the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html#TimePickerDialog%28android.content.Context,%20android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29).

As per your requirement, check the reference from here:

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/07/time-picker-in-android-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put a condition to determine if the hour of the day is greater than 12 so you can reduce it by 12 hours and append PM to it. The condition should also determine if the hour of the day is equal to 12 PM in the afternoon so it will just append the PM without reducing it by 12.

```
if (hourOfDay > 12) {
    hourOfDay = hourOfDay - 12;
    String AM_PM = "PM";
} else if (hourOfDay < 12) {
    String AM_PM = "AM";
}else{
    String AM_PM = "PM"; // this means it is 12 in the afternoon
}
```